What if i need 2 cell renderers for one column at a time ho to implement that?
In master detail ag-grid funtionality we have to have cell renderer for the first column as agGroupCellRendere.I need to make a button in the column for every row.
const gridOptions = {
    // enable Master / Detail
    masterDetail: true,

    // the first Column is configured to use agGroupCellRenderer
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'name', cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer' },
        { field: 'account' }
    ],

    // provide Detail Cell Renderer Params
    detailCellRendererParams: {
        // provide the Grid Options to use on the Detail Grid
        detailGridOptions: {
            columnDefs: [
                { field: 'callId' },
                { field: 'direction' },
                { field: 'number'}
            ]
        },
        // get the rows for each Detail Grid
        getDetailRowData: params => {
            params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
        }
    },

    // other grid options ...
}

in this i need to have a button in this column so I need to make a cell renderer to do so. How to achieve that
